# What is the Russian sentence spoken here, and what is the English translation?

Tags: перевод

What is the sentence spoken in this video at 9:58, and what does it mean in English? (It will probably be about painting.) I like the way it sounds. Thanks!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKC_D4DLTlI&t=9m57s

Answer (score 5):

It is «Немножко краска смешивается.» ~ Paint is getting mixed a little, the paints are mixed a bit. She is talking about colours on the canvas, I think.

Answer (score 1):

She say: "Немножко краска смешивается." - "A little paint mixed".